# Oracle Trigger: Show an error in a table in database A if the value does not exist in database B

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I have two tables, but these tables are in DIFFERENT DATABASE. What I am trying to do is to create a trigger that when I update the STUDENT table, and I enter a University that does not exist in UNIVERSITY table, it should show me an error. However I am not getting any errors. Here are my attempts:

Table:

```
 UNIVERSITY - DatabaseA
| Student(PK) | State    |
| A           | X State  |
| B           | Y State  |
| C           | B State  |

 STUDENT - DatabaseB
| Student_Name (PK) | Grade      | University (PK)(FK) |
| James             | D          | A               | 
| Andrew            | HD         | B               | 
| James             | D          | C               |
```

Trigger:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER student_trigger
BEFORE UPDATE ON student
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE temp_count INTEGER; 
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO temp_count 
    FROM university@DatabaseA u
    WHERE u.Student = :OLD.Student;

    IF (temp_count < 1) 
        THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20101, 'Error:Uni doesnt exist');
    END IF;
END;
```

This works and update is successfully:

```
UPDATE student
SET Grade = 'C'
WHERE Student_Name = 'James'
AND University = 'A';
```

But when I execute the update as shown below where I try to update where the university does not exist in the University table in DatabaseA, I get no error and just get '0 rows affected':

```
UPDATE student
SET Grade = 'C'
WHERE Student_Name = 'James'
AND University = 'something_that_doesnt_exist';
```

How do I get it to show an error if the university name that I put in does not exist in the UNIVERSITY table in DatabaseA

Comment: Why does a table called `University` have a primary key column called `Student`?  Your data structure seems very awkward.

Comment: Sorry the student table have a composite primary key consisting of university and student name. I edited my question

Comment: Please adjust tablename of your update statements from `room` to `student`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your update trigger is executed *for each row* of the table *that meets the conditions of your update statement*.

In the second case

```
UPDATE student
SET Grade = 'C'
WHERE Student_Name = 'James'
AND University = 'something_that_doesnt_exist';
```

no rows are affected, therefore the trigger is not executed at all.

Comment: ahhh that makes perfect sense, thank you Frank really appreciate your help